# Update panel and usercontrols

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

I have two web user controls nested inside of an update panel. The events inside the user controls do not appear to trigger the panel.  For testing, I have set the method the fires to sleep for 3 seconds, and added an update progress panel to the page.  The update progress panel never comes up and the page reflashes as usual.

The user controls work correctly and do what they need to do, but I would like to make them ajaxy and pretty.

Is there a special method for adding usercontrols to an update so the postback works correctly?

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                UPDATING...</ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="order">
                    <keg:BeerList runat="server" ID="uxBeerList" />
                    <kegcart:ShoppingCart runat="server" ID="uxCustomerCart" />
                    <br class="clearfloat" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    Protected Sub uxBeerList_AddItem(ByVal item As KegData.IOrderableItem) Handles uxBeerList.AddItem
            uxCustomerCart.AddItemToOrder(item)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to post some example code

Comment: Please also note whether or not you have Asych. Postbacks working in other areas of the same site (preferably using the same web.config)

Comment: no postbacks anywhere else, but i can create the same page without usercontrols and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to setup anything specific.  However, without a code sample it will be hard for us to diagnose.

The one thing you will want to ensure is that you do not have the ChildrenAsTriggers set to false.

Comment: Added sample code.  I am not setting ChildrenAsTriggers, so it should default to True.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put

the UpdateProgress & ProgressTemplate tags inside of the UpdatePanel and ContentTemplate tags. This should then work, unless there's an issue somewhere else which is difficult to tell from the code provided.